# Flipping the direction of bezier curve path for a crown molding

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I am trying to make a crown molding with bezier curves where I make a path along the wall, and then in Bevel object, selecting a profile of the molding that I made with another bezier curve. When I do this, it works, but is in the wrong direction. I need the molding to be facing outwards, away from the wall, rather than inwards.

[image: Bezier curve path along wall]

[image: Molding facing wrong direction]

[image: Mold profile]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the bevel object in •[edit]• mode, see yellow arrow in image below,

- Try rotating in X or Y or Z axis to see result in the final mesh.
- Try 90 degrees and -90 degrees.

[image]

Comment: That worked! Much appreciated!